# Destroy is not working properly in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails-3 with psql

My problem is little bit funny. I don't know why its not working.

When I'm using this code everything is working perfectly

```
if @sd.supplier_document_users.first.status.eql?("Waiting")
   @sd.supplier_document_send_to_fi_user_lists.destroy_all
   @sd.supplier_document_users.first.destroy
   @fi_destroy_status = true
end
```

Here `@sd.supplier_document_users` return `[]` after this

When I add this if condition (if !@sd.supplier_document_users.blank?) like this

```
if !@sd.supplier_document_users.blank?              
    if @sd.supplier_document_users.first.status.eql?("Waiting")
       @sd.supplier_document_send_to_fi_user_lists.destroy_all
       @sd.supplier_document_users.first.destroy
       @fi_destroy_status = true
    end
end
```

Here `@sd.supplier_document_users` return value which I destroy above `( @sd.supplier_document_users.first.destroy)`

I don't know what ghost come in my code.

Comment: `blank?` doesn't destroy anything if that's what you meant.

Comment: blank? I was using only for checking if that table is empty or not.

Comment: firstly get your code review done at codereview.stackexchange.com. Why do not you have a reference to object being destroyed and then pry/puts(debug) to check whether that really gets destroyed, your log file will have DELETE query too

Comment: Amol Pujari @spickermann code solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the result of `@sd.supplier_document_users` may be cached by Rails.

In your second example `@sd.supplier_document_users.blank?` load all users in an array and caches the result. If you call `@sd.supplier_document_users` later again it is still the same array. If you want to make sure you reload the array, call: `@sd.supplier_document_users(true)`.

It works in your first example, because there you do not load all users. Just the first (on database level, not on array level).

Answer (score 1):

arguably it is much clearer with any?:

```
if @sd.supplier_document_users.any?              
    if @sd.supplier_document_users.first.status.eql?("Waiting")
       @sd.supplier_document_send_to_fi_user_lists.destroy_all
       @sd.supplier_document_users.first.destroy
       @fi_destroy_status = true
    end
end
```

Or you could write it like this:

```
if @sd.supplier_document_users.any? && @sd.supplier_document_users.first.status.eql?("Waiting")
   @sd.supplier_document_send_to_fi_user_lists.destroy_all
   @sd.supplier_document_users.first.destroy
   @fi_destroy_status = true
end
```

In any case how it is not working? Does the code inside an inner if is not being executed or are you expecting some sort of return value from if?

Comment: thanx @Tumas for your effort.  Learn new thing any? :)